# What is wrong with my sorting function [Arrays]?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm still new to coding and I've been trying to teach myself using various books.
One of the exercises require me to check if a random array[10] is sorted or not. If NOT SORTED, I have to sort the array using insertion sort.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int findSmallestNumber (int values[], int index);
void swap (int values[], int firstIndex, int secondIndex);
void sort(int values[]);

void sort(int values[])
{
   for (int i =0; i<10; i++)
   {
      int index = findSmallestNumber (values, i);
      swap(values, i, index);
   }
}

int findSmallestNumber (int values[], int index)
{
   int index_of_smallest_number = index;
   for (int i=index+1 ; i<10; i++)
   {
      if ( values[i] < values[index_of_smallest_number])
      {
         index_of_smallest_number = i;
      }
   }
   return index_of_smallest_number;
}

void swap (int values[], int firstIndex, int secondIndex)
{
   int temp = values[firstIndex];
   values[firstIndex] = values[secondIndex];
   temp = values[secondIndex];
}  

int main()
{
   int array[10];
   srand(time(NULL));

   for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
      array[i] = rand() % 100; //create an array with random numbers
   }

   sort(array);
}
```

The code runs without any compiler errors, however it doesn't sort out the array properly.
Here is the [results when I run the full program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgX2X.jpg)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your swap doesn't swap, you have to swap the left and right side of the last line.

Comment: Did you debug your code step by step to see how your logic is operating?

Comment: @MikeMB O gosh, I can't believe I made such a careless mistake. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: What do you think `temp = values[secondIndex];` does?

Comment: See R Sahu's comment and your problem is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your `swap()` function, you are not assigning the value you held in `temp` "back" to its supposed position:

```
void swap(int values[], int firstIndex, int secondIndex)
{
    int temp = values[firstIndex];
    values[firstIndex] = values[secondIndex];
    values[secondIndex] = temp ; // this is the fix
}
```